# Calling Object properties from different classes in C#

Tags: c#, object

I have created an object that holds 4 properties, and will get created and used in Class A. However, I need to call some of the properties in 2 other classes (Class B and Class C). I'm not able to do this, and I'm confident that I am missing something very simple. Here is my object creation class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class ConfigItems
    {
        public static string W { get; set; }
        public static string X { get; set; }
        public static int Y { get; set; }
        public static Int64 Z { get; set; }

        public ConfigItems(string w, string x, int y, Int64 z) {
            W= w;
            X= x;
            Y= y;
            Z= z;
        }

    }
}
```

In my Main class, this is how I'm creating the object, which works just fine as long as I remain in the Main class:

```
    namespace Test 
{
       public class Main 
{
        ConfigItems mainSetup = new ConfigItems(w, x, y, z);
       console.writeline(mainSetup.x);
        }
    }
```

In the Main class when I create the object, I can keep calling it. When I move to a new class and try to call the same object, I cannot. It is out of scope, and I'm not certain as to why.

```
namespace SomeClass 
{
   public class StuffHere
{
   Console.Writeline(mainSetup.x);
}
}
```

mainSetup.x in the above will not return anything, because it is out of scope. I have tried using both static and non-static properties in the object creation lass (ConfigItems) but I still can't call mainSetup.x outside of the Main class

Comment: Welcome to SO please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `mainSetup` surely does only exist in the scope where you define it, in your case this is `MainClass`. You didn´t providethe code, where you want to use that variable, though. Having said this, what exactly does "calling the property of mainSetup.x does not work" mean? Please show the relevant code and the error you get.

Comment: Please add a full sample that reproduces the problem you're experiencing

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? The scope of the instance is limited (apparently to your Main method). Also it is a static property, so you need `ConfigItems.X` (and then also note the upper case - C# is case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your properties as `static`, therefore they are not instance members, but members of the class. Remove the static keyword.

```
public string X { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is not static! so you can't access class's property directly.

You have two way:

1. Make your class static.

```
public static class ConfigItems {
}
```

2. Pass the class context from initialer class (A) to other classes (B or C).

Class A:

```
ConfigItems mainSetup = new ConfigItems(w, x, y, z);
SecondClass b = new SecondClass(mainSetup);
```

Class B or C:

```
public class SecondClass {
    public SecondClass (ConfigItems config) {
        // You have the ConfigItems class here and you can do anything with it
    }
}
```

Comment: The class does not have to be `static` itself in order to call any of its `static` members.

Answer (score 0):

you can access them directly using CalssName

```
ConfigItems.X;
```